# proxy for python api.ai

Tags: python, proxy, dialogflow-es

I am using python SDK of api.ai. I am working behind coporate proxy and I got firewall access to 443 port too. I can call other external API like wt.ai. But I cant call APIs of api.ai.

```
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)


request = ai.text_request()


request.lang = 'en'  # optional, default value equal 'en'

request.session_id = "<SESSION ID, UNIQUE FOR EACH USER>"

request.query = "Hello"

response = request.getresponse()

print (response.read())
```

I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DialogAssistant.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "DialogAssistant.py", line 38, in main
    response = request.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apiai\requests\request.py", line 128, in getresponse
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apiai\requests\request.py", line 82, in _connect
    self._connection.connect()
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\chathuranga_08290\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

how to fix this?